# how to run wildfly as a service in domain mode

Tags: linux, jboss, scripting

**I have wild-fly and want to run it as a service in domain mode as per the script available in git hub**
**https://gist.github.com/sukharevd/6087988**

**installed and made it as service but it is in standalone mode.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**to run wildfly as a domain mode in service edit wildfly file available in /etc/init.d/wildfly**

**vim /etc/init.d/wildfly**

**change 
from
JBOSS_MODE=standalone
to
JBOSS_MODE=domain**